# CentOS requires root pw for network pref changes

Tags: centos, networking, root

Why does CentOS require root privileges to configure the preference panels?  It seems like sudoer access really should be sufficient for this.  Is it possible to change this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to bypass this would be (assuming appropriate `sudoers` rights) to prefix the appropriate command with `sudo`, e.g.

```
sudo system-config-users
```

Otherwise, with some digging:

```
% ls -l =system-config-users
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 24  2015 /usr/bin/system-config-users -> consolehelper
```

Which with some yet more digging turns up the `userhelper` program whose manual contains this tidbit:

```
   UGROUPS
          A comma-separated list of groups whose members will be authenti-
          cated as if USER were set to the special value  <user>.  If  the
          invoking  user  is not a member of one of these groups, the name
          defined in USER will be used as  normal.
```

Centos 7 appears to set the `wheel` group by default:

```
# cat /etc/security/console.apps/config-util 
USER=root
UGROUPS=wheel
#
```

So in theory if your user is in the `wheel` group, those password prompts should ask for your password. Is your user in the `wheel` group?

Comment: Yeah, in the wheel group.  Still requests root password (and wont take mine).